# How do I get my git commit history back to normal?

Tags: git

I work on my local 'master' branch and then periodically jump over to my 'release' branch and type

```
% git merge master
```

And that was working just fine for quite a while--in my commit history on BitBucket, I'd see checkins to mainline followed by a merge to release. But now when I merge and push to origin/release, I just see the commits--they don't look like a merge at all. Apparently, I know just enough to be dangerous because I can't figure out what I did to mess things up.

I'm not even sure how to Google this problem, so even a RTFM response with a URL would be appreciated.

Here's what my master branch looks like. What is going on here?

```
* 0a41d90 
*   77127c8 
|\  
| * a9e803b 
| * 76bf8dd 
| *   03f6c4d 
| |\  
| * \   fffbcab 
| |\ \  
| * \ \   7e1064f 
| |\ \ \  
| * \ \ \   155b815 
| |\ \ \ \  
| * | | | | 6990b2f 
| * | | | |   6fc18fd 
| |\ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \   8b63f1b 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \   feddf35 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \   8eeedd4 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   f4bc862 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   6595d3b 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   245ea26 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   895733b 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   fa22b61 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | | d56755e 
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | |   1afb89d 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   9ef936c 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   77adbee 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   d37e67d 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   7e7e8fa 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   3cebafd 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   67327ce 
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 2ddd17c 
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 51d241f 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | acf8dd7 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 238ba1c 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | b2987cf 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 60c1528 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | fa4152b 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 35f3451 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 929990d 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 52d07ac 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0b010f8 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 38bdc49 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 67e2693 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | d98cc92 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 8f35a00 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | cac033c 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | d7ebb20 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 2a3b53f 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 937080c 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 3a925b8 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | f5b757b 
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 398daad 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | 42f3300 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | eb455d7 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | dc7db8a 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | 0f09b40 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | 7c1271e 
* | | | | | | | | | e9a9582 
* | | | | | | | | | 92fa1dd 
* | | | | | | | | | fb0a0c2 
* | | | | | | | | | 2a6bccf 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | b1cc90f 
* | | | | | | | | 2215950 
* | | | | | | | | 26e1f4e 
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | bde1089 
* | | | | | | | 39b7af7 
* | | | | | | | 7626f37 
* | | | | | | | 152a71e 
* | | | | | | | 01a8351 
* | | | | | | | 5455aad 
* | | | | | | | 5c3a2e4 
* | | | | | | | e003d70 
| |_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | |   
* | | | | | | 2494a37 
| |_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | |   
* | | | | | 7fa4f9d 
* | | | | | 98781b0 
| |_|_|_|/  
|/| | | |   
* | | | | 85047a2 
* | | | | b81af73 
* | | | | cfbf163 
| |_|_|/  
|/| | |   
* | | | f4ce570 
| |_|/  
|/| |   
* | | 7124029 
| |/  
|/|   
* | 86e30a9 
* | b8609a7 
* | b7ebd85 
* | effb05a 
* | c2511fa 
* | 154eaf3 
* | 9aaf759 
* | 8d57e05 
* | 56bc946 
* | 4e46bfb 
* | 9ee3c38 
* | 8f3bec0
|/  
* 5e4e6e0 
* f122342
```

Comment: The order you pass the arguments to `git log` affects the layout. Try both `git log --decorate --oneline --graph master release` and `git log --decorate --oneline --graph release master`. Does one of them look like what you expected, and the other like what you posted above?

Comment: The whole top of this graph look like merges to me. Anywhere you have "|\" with a "*" above them, that's a merge.

Comment: @raek No, they both have the same shape. :-\

Answer (score 0):

If there were no commits on your `release` branch, then each merge of master into release would be a *fast-forward* merge (just advances the branch label along the "line" and does not create a new "line").

At some point you committed 51d241f and 2ddd17c to your `release` branch.  From that point on (starting with commit 7124029 on `master`), every time you committed to `master` and then merged `master` into `release`, a *fast-forward* merge wasn't possible, so you created another "line" in your graph to record the merge.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, you're saying there's nothing amiss here? What would cause the lines to start heading back to the left after 2ddd17c?